# Error while sending email with SMTP and Gmail. certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail

I send emails through `gmail` by using the Python `smtplib`. However, when I run the following code:

```
import ssl
import smtplib
context = ssl.create_default_context()
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls(context=context)
```

I receive an error at the line `server.starttls(context=context)`. The error that I receive is as follows:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL : CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

I am using a `Windows` system. I have tried a couple of different things by browsing various forum posts. However, nothing has worked. I also tried

```
pip uninstall certifi
pip install certifi
```

A common response on forums is to run `Certificates.command` or something like that. However, I cannot find that file on Windows. I am running `python 3.8.2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade pip to the latest version:

   ```
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
2. Upgrade the `certifi` packages:

   ```
   pip install certifi --upgrade
   ```

I did try upgrading `certifi`, but upgrading pip was a necessary prerequisite.